# Conditionally include meta-data in Android manifest file

Tags: android, gradle

Is there way to conditionally include `meta-data` element in Android manifest file based on value set in Gradle.  I am able to do following (using `resValue` to set `<some_value>` in `build.gradle`) but haven't been able to find way to include/exclude complete `meta-data` element.

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="<some_setting>"
        android:value="@string/<some_value>" />
```

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution? I have the same problem... Thanks

Comment: @Blunderer no, not yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat of a hack but only way I've been able to address this is by having something like following (have changed names in example) in `build.gradle` (am using this in context of having different build flavors as well but isn't dependent on that)...I think there's probably some additional smarts that can be done around manifest merging that would make this a bit cleaner as well.  `myFlag` is coming from a `project.hasProperty()` value I'm passing in as part of `Fastlane` script

```
        sourceSets {
            flavor1 {
                if (myFlag == "true") {
                    manifest.srcFile "src/flavor1_flag/AndroidManifest.xml"
                } else {
                    manifest.srcFile "src/flavor1/AndroidManifest.xml"
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<meta-data android:name="string"
           android:resource="resource specification"
           android:value="string" />
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what's being suggested but I don't think this solves what I'm trying to do?  I need ability to conditionally include/exclude the full `<meta-data>` element.