# How to dynamically edit Android Manifest file with respect to environment variables in Gradle script

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I have a variable in my "strings.xml" file called "override_iap"
I would like to edit my Android Manifest file in gradle script if the value of "override_iap" is "true".

The string.xml file:

```
<resources>
  <string name=“override_iap”>false</string>
</resources>
```

I would like to remove the BILLING uses-permission if override_iap is true

```
<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android=“http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android” package=“…”>
 <uses-permission android:name=“android.permission.INTERNET”/>
  <uses-permission android:name=“com.android.vending.BILLING”/>
</manifest>
```

I tried below script but does not work:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def processorTask = output.processManifestProvider.getOrNull()
        processorTask.doLast { task ->
            def srcManifestFile = "${project.rootDir}/app/src/main//AndroidManifest.xml"
            def manifestContent = new File(srcManifestFile).getText()
            //def xml= new XmlParser().parseText(manifestContent)
            def xml = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(manifestContent)

            def nodeRemove = "uses-permission"
            def nodeToDel=xml.manifest.children().findAll { it.name().equals(nodeRemove) }
            def parent = nodeToDel.parent()
            parent.remove(nodeToDel)

            def serializeContent = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
            new File("${project.rootDir}/app/src/main//AndroidManifest.xml").write(serializeContent)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to define an XmlParser to load your xml data and then specify the manifest source file based on it.

```
def rootNode = "${project.rootDir}/app/src/mobileDebug/res/values/strings.xml"
def rootContent = new File(rootNode).getText()
project.logger.lifecycle(rootContent)
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(rootContent)

def override_iap_node = xml.'*'.find {node -> node.@name == "override_iap"}
def override_iap = override_iap_node.text()
```

then as it mentioned in earlier answers you can do:

```
sourceSets {
    mobileDebug {
        if (override_iap == "true") {
            manifest.srcFile "${project.rootDir}/app/src/main/custom_iap/AndroidManifest.xml"
        } else {
            manifest.srcFile "${project.rootDir}/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I neeeded to do something similar a while back and ended up using different manifest files (not sure though if there's cleaner way)....had something like following then in `build.gradle`

```
        def override_iap = project.hasProperty('override_iap') ? project.property('v') : "false"
        sourceSets {
            custom {
                if (override_iap == "true") {
                    manifest.srcFile "src/custom__iap/AndroidManifest.xml"
                } else {
                    manifest.srcFile "src/custom/AndroidManifest.xml"
                }
            }
        }
```

The issue I had was for `meta-data` entry in manifest file so perhaps, as mentioned, there's easier way to do this in your case - [Conditionally include meta-data in Android manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130918/conditionally-include-meta-data-in-android-manifest-file)

Comment: `custom` was just example from my project here....it's the build variant I have. If you don't have any build variants then I think you can just replace `custom` with `main`

Comment: Thank Johan!
I tried this solution and it is always falling back to "false". Apparently it is not finding the "override_iap" properly. I have different build variables such as: mobileDebug, mobileAlpha, androidTvDebug, and etc.
I have the similar string.xml file for each one. How should I specify that it should look after the string.xml in mobileDebug? I also changed the "custom" to "mobileDebug"

Comment: Yeah it was my mistake. I changed to mobileDebug but still can't find the override_iap

Comment: In my case I'm providing that property on command line when invoking gradle....but you could set it differently depending on your need.  You can also have completely different build variant for this in case you don't need to add that check....just have the appropriate `AndroidManiifest.xml` in folder for that variiant.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have two manifest files this solution works:

```
def rootNode = "${project.rootDir}/app/src/mobileRelease/res/values/strings.xml"
    def rootContent = new File(rootNode).getText()
    def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(rootContent)
    def override_iap_node = xml.'*'.find {node -> node.@name == "override_iap"}
    def override_iap = override_iap_node.text()

    if(override_iap == "true") {
        def manifestNode = "${project.rootDir}/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml"
        def manifestContent = new File(manifestNode).getText()
        def manifestXML = new XmlSlurper().parseText(manifestContent)
        manifestXML.'*'.find { node -> node.'@android:name' == "com.android.vending.BILLING" }.replaceNode {
        }
        def serializeContent = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(manifestXML)
        new File("${project.rootDir}/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml").write(serializeContent)
    }
```